# Why is the picture not inserted?

Tags: graphics, errors, geometry

When I `pdflatex` the text below it doesn't insert the picture, but writes the name of the file instead (pic).

And the geometry line gives the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

The picture I am using is at http://bayfiles.com/file/jIHB/oeWKYv/pic.pdf and the floatrow package [from](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty).

**Question**

Can anyone see what is wrong?

**Text**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\usepackage{aeguill}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{margin=10pt,paperwidth=\textwidth+20pt,paperheight=\textheight+20pt}

\begin{document}

The first paragraph.

\begin{figure}  
\includegraphics{pic}
\end{figure}

And the second.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

Remove the draft option which just tells latex to print the file name and not include the image.

Add

```
 \usepackage{calc}
```

To allow infix `+` syntax in

```
\geometry{margin=10pt,paperwidth=\textwidth+20pt,paperheight=\textheight+20pt}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without loading other packages as many as possible, use `\geometry{margin=10pt,paperwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth+20pt\relax,paperheight=\dimexpr\textheight+20pt\relax}`