# Tikzposter images not displaying

Tags: graphics, tikzposter

When I compile, the images (.jpg and .png) inserted in my tikzposter document don't display - I just get a box with the image path instead. It looks like this:

[image]

Existing answers to similar questions ([Why is the picture not inserted?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66919/why-is-the-picture-not-inserted), [Images not showing up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240172/images-not-showing-up) and [Images not visible in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27931/images-not-visible-in-pdf)) haven't worked for me.

The images did display in this document before, and I can't figure out what I did to stop them showing up.

I've tried commenting out most of the preamble lines individually, but with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}
\institute{Institution}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usetheme{Basic}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}

\column{0.33}
\block{Column 1}{

\begin{tikzfigure}[Test\label{here}]
\includegraphics[width=0.33\colwidth]{images/Test.png}
\end{tikzfigure}

 }

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using this code? It works for me with `example-image.png` instead of `images/Test.png`.

Comment: I'm using Sharelatex (www.sharelatex.com). I definitely have this code not producing the image. But - when I copy the code into a new 'project' and try again, it works perfectly. Could it be a problem with some of the other files I have in this project? All I have are the images folder and three .tex files (one for testing pictures and one for snippets of unused code). If not, I guess maybe it's a problem with Sharelatex rather than my code.

Comment: I should also have mentioned that I'm getting this error message: `Package tikzposter Warning: Unknown Option draft. on input line 204`. I don't get this error in the separate 'project', however. So is this the culprit?

Comment: OK, I solved this by copying all my code and files into a new 'project'. The images now work perfectly and the error messages don't reappear. Since nothing else has changed I assume this is a bug with Sharelatex so I'll close this question.

Comment: `draft` option is the culprit. `draft` option from `graphicx` does the result you get. Some of your files introduces it.

Answer (score 1):

Answered as above. Solved by moving all code and image files to a new Sharelatex 'project'. I assume it's a bug with Sharelatex so I'll report it accordingly.